# Read CSV and make a list with specific values

Tags: c#, list, csv

I am new to C# and I have been trying to understand how I can read from a CSV file a specific value. My file has the following format

```
08/11/2012 01:00:00,28/11/2012 01:00:00,29/11/2012 01:00:00,88,
08/11/2012 01:00:00,29/11/2012 01:00:00,30/11/2012 01:00:00,88,
08/11/2012 01:00:00,30/11/2012 01:00:00,01/12/2012 01:00:00,88,
08/11/2012 01:00:00,01/12/2012 01:00:00,02/12/2012 01:00:00,90.25,
08/11/2012 01:00:00,02/12/2012 01:00:00,03/12/2012 01:00:00,90.25,
```

I want to read and save to a list as string the last values (i.e `88 90.25`, etc). I tried everything that I found until now here to this forum but it is not working in my case.

I want to do this because I want to compare this list with another string list that take this values from an XML file which is produced from another model that I run. Thanks a lot for your help!

**this csv file contains ~55000 lines with the above format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var values = File.ReadAllLines("").Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { ',' })[3]);
```

Small edit - typo. Use this example to test:

```
  List<string> lines = new List<string>();
  lines.Add("08/11/2012 01:00:00,28/11/2012 01:00:00,29/11/2012 01:00:00,88,");
  lines.Add("08/11/2012 01:00:00,29/11/2012 01:00:00,30/11/2012 01:00:00,88,");
  var values = lines.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { ',' })[3]);
```

Retrieves 88, 88 in a list.

Answer (score 0):

if your values are like this and don't include "," inside it's values:

```
TextReader tr1 = new StreamReader(CSVFileName, true);

var Data = tr1.ReadToEnd().Split('\n')
    .Where(l => l.Length > 0)  //nonempty strings
    .Skip(1)               // skip header if it has one
    .Select(s => s.Trim())   // delete whitespace
    .Select(l => l.Split(',')) // get arrays of values
    .Select(l => new { Date_1 = l[0], 
                       Date_2 = l[1], 
                       Date_3 = l[2], 
                       Val = l[3] });
```

and then you can use this object with `foreach` or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] numbers = fileText.Split('\n').Select(x => double.Parse(x.Split(',')[3])).ToArray();
string numbersJoined = string.Join(" ", numbers);
```